# Visual Studio View Code on Multiple Files at Once

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm in the process of migrating some Web Sites to Web Applications, using Visual Studio 2017. One thing I can't seem to figure out is how do I open multiple .cs files at the same time? I can open the .aspx file for them easy enough by right clicking and choosing Open. I can view the code behind on a single page at a time by right clicking and choosing View Code. In the old Web Sites I could right click multiple files at once and select View Code, however, it appears in Web Applications that option has been replaced with "View Code Gen File" which isn't the same thing. It's painfully slow to open a single page at a time so hopefully there is a setting I am just not finding.

EDIT: As requested, uploading screenshots. Only .aspx files are selected but when more than one is selected the "View Source" option is no longer there. Also I should note that if multiple are selected in Solution Explorer, pressing F7 also has no effect, though that keystroke does work to View Source of a single file at a time.

[image: Single File]

[image: Multiple Files]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further experimentation, I now see what you see and I agree that it's something that Microsoft broke along the way. In fact, in your own image, if you single-select an aspx file in Solution Explorer then you can see the "<>" icon appear in the button bar at the top of Solution Explorer. But that icon disappears whenever you select two or more aspx files.

I've done a lot of work with Visual Studio over the years and I can't imagine any justifiable reason why Microsoft would have deliberately removed the View Code option from the context menu for multiply selected aspx files.

**This appears to be a bona fide bug that should be reported to Microsoft.**

Meanwhile, as a workaround, use the File | Open option in Visual Studio 2017 and, in the resulting Open File dialog box, simply multi-select any .cs files you need (this dialog box allows you to multi-select files and open all of them at once).

Comment: Still relatively convoluted as it takes several extra steps to browse to the files, opening multiple folders when there's more than one project in the solution. A little better than opening one at a time but still not a great solution. Seems ridiculous to have removed the right click option.

Comment: See my amended answer.

Comment: The option is most definitely not present for me when selecting multiple files. Edited original post with screenshots.

Comment: Thanks for the images, that helped. I amended my reply/answer once again--I know it's not the answer you were seeking, but I think it's the most practical answer for now--until Microsoft fixes the problem in a software update.